# Logout request from Javascript to Flask

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to logout user from my web application using Flask-Login.

Here's my Javascript function:

```
function logout() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", "http://myaddress/logout", true);
  req.withCredentials = true;
  req.send();
```

Here's my Python function:

```
@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout_function():
    logout_user() # Built-in Flask-Login function
    return app.send_static_file('login.html')
```

When I send my request from Javascript I receive 200, but the page remains still, because redirect doesn't happen. I tried changing the last line of Python function to `return redirect(url_for('login_function'))`, but it didn't help.

Could it be my Javascript function that causes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect to the logout page using JavaScript:

```
function logout() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           window.location.replace("http://myaddress/logout.html");
        }
    };
    req.open("POST", "http://myaddress/logout", true);
    req.withCredentials = true;
    req.send();
}
```

You can hardcode the logout-URL like shown above. In this case you just need to return a 200 status code:

```
return ('', 200)
```

If you want to return the url, you can access it with `req.responseText`:

Flask:

```
return (url_for('login_function'), 200)
```

JavaScript:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    window.location.replace(req.responseText);
}
```